# Reset browser zoom level when a page change

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have a mobile site that loads pages with ajax. One of the features I would like to add is to reset the zoom level when a page changes.

Is there a good method to detect if a user zoomed the view while viewing a page?

Until now I've managed to do the check for pinch zoom. But sometimes there is double tap zooming too ..

Comment: When you say page changes, you can just add the meta properties on each of those pages setting initial-scale and maximum-scale as 1.0 ...This would make the page load in 100% zoom mode.

Comment: Reseting the viewport content attribute will make a little "blink" effect on some devices, and I want to do that only when necessary (user has modified zoom level).

Answer (score 9):

You can get the users zoom level by comparing the innerWidth and document width. Document width is the width of the device in pixels, inner width is the pixels which are on screen when zoomed (in relation to what the document width initially was). I have tested this on android (ICS and Jellybean), and iOS (5 and 6) and it seems to work. Note, I do not have my viewport set to device width or height

```
  ratio = document.width / window.innerWidth

  if ratio > 1 then zommed else notZoomed
```

Then you can do this check whenever a user makes a double tap or a pinch.

Comment: It doesn't work on Firefox (ratio is NaN) but it works well on Android default browser and iOS.

Comment: you need to use document.body.clientWidth instead of document.width which is no longer supported

Comment: If viewport is not set to device-width it may be, that not zoomed doesn't return 1. So be carful with this solution and check exactly which browser returns what values.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the contents of the [meta name="viewport"] tag using javascript to set the zoom level, unfortunately i haven't found a way to detect what the current zoom level is

Comment: I don't think you want to be messing with the viewport with this. That would mean that the user is still zoomed in in the browser, but you are changing the viewport to fix it. I'm guessing that will become very messy very soon. Better to use the solution by Khallil Mangalji with fadomire's fix.

Comment: The viewport meta tag has maximum-scale and minimum-scale properties. Changing those should clamp the zoom to a value that you specify. (Untested , I haven't done this sort of thing in a while)